# Node.js selecting the latest entry of two columns and assigning the values to variables

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a MYSQL table which only has 4 columns, one of which is an id auto incrementing column.  I need to find the most recent, highest id, entries for two columns called command and extra.  I am able to successfully do this for one column, but code doesn't seem to like my attempt at the second one.  Does anyone understand where I am going wrong?

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'myuser',
  password : 'mypass',
  database : 'mydb'


var pulsesql = 'SELECT command,extra FROM motoron2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
con.query(pulsesql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) { 
        throw err; 
    }
    // access result inside the callback
    console.log(result);
    var precommand = result[0];
    var preextra = result[1];
    command = precommand.command;
    extra = preextra.extra
    client.publish(topic,"shutdown=${command},extra=${extra}", {qos:1});
    console.log("shutdown=${command} and extra=${extra}");
});
```

I am seeing the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'extra' of undefined
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/user/etc/domain/bin/boardservermanager2.js:111:22)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/user/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/home/user/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/user/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/user/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/home/user/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/user/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/user/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/user/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/user/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
```

Comment: The issue is with you query. 
`SELECT command,extra FROM motoron2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`. You have added LIMIT 1 which will only give you 1 record matching the query and you are trying to access the second record by doing result[1] which will give you undefined. If you need two records you need to make it to LIMIT 2 or If you do not want to add any limit to the results then just remove the LIMIT.

Comment: I changed this and it solved some problems, after this another issue was found in the code. The console log code should be corrected to use the ` instead of " .  But there appears to be one more issue related to the publish function line